# Turn/flip for the two layouts with button click

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layouts(xml files) and I want to flip from one page to another, the two xml files are main.xml and register.xml, if I click signin button in main.xml the page should turn and show register.xml  and also in register.xml if I click the submit button it  should turn to main.xml I tried a lot with the activity and i coldnt do it as I am new to android

please someone  share the code for me,

here is my two xml codes

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:background="@drawable/loginapp">
 <Button  android:layout_width="49px"  android:layout_height="44px" android:background="@drawable/login_home_btn_over_green" android:id="@+id/widget38"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="25dip" android:layout_height="177dip" android:background="@drawable/login_form_bg_green" android:layout_width="296dip">
     <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"  android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px" android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="85dip" android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
     <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"  android:id="@+id/passwordBox" android:layout_width="200px" android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginTop="45dip" android:layout_marginLeft="85dip" android:inputType="text|textVisiblePassword" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_three" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_below="@+id/ll_two" android:gravity="center">
      <Button 
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:text="New user"/>
 </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

register.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="0">

    <TableRow>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" REGISTER:"/>    
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Name:"/>
    <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
      android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"   android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="35px" android:layout_width="0dip"></EditText>


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Last Name:"/>
    <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
      android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px"  android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" android:maxLines="1"
       android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:inputType="text" 
       android:layout_height="35px"></EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email:"/>
    <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px"
      android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"  android:layout_weight="1"
       android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip"  
       android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="35px">
       </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mobile No:"/>
    <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip" 
     android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px"   android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
       android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="35px">
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>



  <TableRow>
  <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Register"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
          android:padding="3dip"
          android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
          android:layout_marginRight="90dip"
          android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
          android:layout_column="1"

          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

HERE ARE MY JAVA FILES

login.java

```
package com.android;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Login extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Register.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Register.java

```
package com.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Register extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }}
```

Comment: From the DDMS and LOGCAT, I think the code is fine (now).  It looks like there is something else going on on that device/emulator.  Perhaps waiting for an debugger.  Try shutting down the eclipse, restarting the emulator and/or unplugging the hardware device.  If it is an emulator, wipe the user data upon restart.  Before you launch with Eclipse again, use 'run' instead of debug.

Comment: Minor detail: You should not use com.android as your package name, but rather an domain that you're associated with, like com.your-company.cardioworld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Activity's and Intents

You will want to create two Activity's. One for your Main, on for your Sign-in Screen. Each of this Activity's gets a Layout (like you defined them in XML).

To open a new Activity or get back to another Activity, [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) are used. I created a tutorial on how to do this, it can be found [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/223914-activities-intents-and-something-on-events/).

### What about your code

Okay, first things first: In your XML Layout-definition, you can use the '[onClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)'-Attribute to define a method name which is called, when your button gets clicked (like shown in the Tutorial above).

Also, if any errors occurs in your code and you have no idea where the error lies, you can use Androids [Logging mechanism](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to find it out. To see the Log-Output in Eclipse, you need to open a new view: *Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Android -> LogCat*. You should get an Exception, post the Exception-Output here.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth  thanks a lot man,  but I cant understand how to flip the two layouts,  I couldn't able to explore coz I should deal with two layouts

Comment: The only reaseon why one Activity would have two Layouts: If you want another Layout for the Landscape mode. Just use two Activitys and Intents to communicate between the two.

Comment: @Lukas depending on a parameter from the launching intent (given the case there is one, of course), Raghu could choose which layout to use in setContentView() ... I agree it's not a practical nor a recommended option. Ideally every layout should have an activity... But it's an option after all.

Comment: @Vicente But, if every Layout has it's own buttons, then those buttons have their own function. Why would you put all those functions in one Class if you could split them up in two?

Comment: @Lukas Knuth  As u said I did the same , but I couldnt  able to see the output whenever I am running the application ,its closing on the emulator, plz view the above code once , whats d prblm with that

Comment: Activate the LogCat View in Eclipse (see my Post) and Post the Exception you're getting, and all the Infos.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth plz see the errors above I added in the subject part

Comment: @Lukas Knuth Hi, thanks a lot for ur cooperation ,now its its working fine  and I want to know for the same code, how can we add 3drotate animation functionality so that the when we click the  newuser button the first layout will rotate and viceversa, waiting 4 reply

Comment: Stop asking this "Gimme the Codz"-Questions. Try it yourself and we'll help you with any error you come up with and can't fix by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put the register.class in the AndroidManifest.xml? Should look something like this

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name=".login"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Register"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but how can we do it for 3d rotation of layouts,I tried some examples but its not working for layouts,any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use setContentView(R.Layout.main) to show the main layout in your java code.  Then, set onClickListener to listen for the user to click "signin" to switch to other view using another setContentView(R.Layout.register).  You can code whatever you like in the onClickListener cases for the buttons you are listening for.

Comment: I wouldn't do that, that's bad practice. Use an Activity for every Layout.