# Switching the layouts through Intents

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layouts(xml files) and I want to flip from one page to another, the two xml files are main.xml and register.xml, if I click signin button in main.xml the page should turn and show register.xml  and also in register.xml if I click the submit button it  should turn to main.xml I tried a lot with the activity and i coldnt do it as I am new to android

please someone  share the code for me,

here is my two xml codes

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:background="@drawable/loginapp">
```

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="25dip" android:layout_height="177dip" android:background="@drawable/login_form_bg_green" android:layout_width="296dip">
 <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"  android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px" android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="85dip" android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
 <EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"  android:id="@+id/passwordBox" android:layout_width="200px" android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginTop="45dip" android:layout_marginLeft="85dip" android:inputType="text|textVisiblePassword" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_three" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_below="@+id/ll_two" android:gravity="center">
  <Button 
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:text="New user"/>
```

register.xml is

```
<TableRow>
 <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView"   
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=" REGISTER:"/>    
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="First Name:"/>
<EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
  android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"   android:layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="35px" android:layout_width="0dip"></EditText>


</TableRow>

<TableRow>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Last Name:"/>
<EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
  android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px"  android:layout_weight="1" 
  android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" android:maxLines="1"
   android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:inputType="text" 
   android:layout_height="35px"></EditText>
</TableRow>


<TableRow>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Email:"/>
<EditText 
 android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px"
  android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"  android:layout_weight="1"
   android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip"  
   android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="35px">
   </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
 <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Mobile No:"/>
<EditText android:layout_marginRight="0dip" 
 android:id="@+id/userNameBox" android:layout_width="200px"   android:layout_weight="1"
  android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
   android:maxLines="1" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:inputType="text" android:layout_height="35px">
    </EditText>

</TableRow>
```

HERE ARE MY JAVA FILES

login.java

```
package com.android;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Login extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button newuser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        newuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Register.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });
    }
}




Register.java


package com.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Register extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }}
```

while debugging the project  these are the DDMS errors I found

Android [Android Application]
    DalvikVM[localhost:8759]
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))
            ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2585
            ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679
            ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
            ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2033
            ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
            Looper.loop() line: 123 
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
            NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
        Thread [<6> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
        Thread [<5> Binder Thread #1] (Running

LOGCAT showing this

04-24 16:24:18.965: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(58): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
04-24 16:24:20.415: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44f2b188 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
04-24 16:24:22.965: WARN/WindowManager(58): App freeze timeout expired.
04-24 16:24:22.965: WARN/WindowManager(58): Force clearing freeze: AppWindowToken{450698d0 token=HistoryRecord{44f2b188 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}}
04-24 16:24:23.645: WARN/GoogleLoginService(180): Device has no accounts: sending Intent { act=com.google.android.gsf.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_MISSING }
04-24 16:24:31.296: WARN/PackageManager(58): Code path for pkg : com.android.cardioworld changing from /data/app/com.android.cardioworld-1.apk to /data/app/com.android.cardioworld-2.apk
04-24 16:24:31.296: WARN/PackageManager(58): Resource path for pkg : com.android.cardioworld changing from /data/app/com.android.cardioworld-1.apk to /data/app/com.android.cardioworld-2.apk
04-24 16:24:34.216: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(58): no available voice recognition services found
04-24 16:24:36.214: WARN/SystemClock(123): Unable to set rtc to 1303642476: Invalid argument
04-24 16:24:41.174: WARN/ActivityThread(318): Application com.android.cardioworld is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
04-24 16:24:50.686: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
04-24 16:24:51.170: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450caa98 com.android.cardioworld/.login}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn/flip for the two layouts with button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763933/turn-flip-for-the-two-layouts-with-button-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Register.java, I can see:

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
```

But before that, there is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.register);
```

However Button01 is not on "register", but in main. There's no button on register at all, is it?

Comment: @Vincenta Plata  Hi, I modified once again ,if possible just view once again and button01 is in register.xml file

Comment: Ummmm no it isn't... At least not in your edit. register.xml has TableLayout as its root node, I guess. And both Button01 and Button02 are inside the main.xml LinearLayout (inside another LinearLayout).

Comment: Soooo just to clarify this: Of course the compiler won't give you any errors 'cos Button01 and Button02 exist. However since Button01 and Button02 are not in your activity, their setOnClickListener will have no effect. Cos you can't click them. My suggestion? Create your Buttons programmatically so you don't get messed up with which is the button you're trying to get. Or use other names instead of Button01 and Button02 and ButtonX. Mnemonics, maybe?

Comment: @Vincenta Plata , actually I modified now properly but its not showing in the subject after saving the edit, in main.xml I have taken button01,button02.  In register.xml I added button 03 at the end but its not showing, can u verify it and let me know the problem

Comment: It's not showing yet. Please, check my previous comment. I think you're only confused with your buttons. The Java code is theoretically OK (if you declared your activities in the manifest, of course). What happens when you click your buttons? An error or something?

Comment: In the emulator application  closing forcefully while debugging

Comment: In Register or in Main? Are your activities declared in your Manifest? Please be more specific / explicit.

Comment: yes declared in manifest properly, if I run the paalication its closing and showing nothing

Comment: DalvikVM[localhost:8718] 
  Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
    
   ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679 
   ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
   ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message)  
   
   Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]   
    line:  
   ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
   NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

Comment: 04-24 14:39:10.093: WARN/ActivityThread(315): Application com.android.cardioworld is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
04-24 14:39:19.519: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
04-24 14:39:20.089: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{45088ed8 com.android.cardioworld/.login}

Comment: @Vincent Plata  These r the type of errors i'm getting ,could u  help to solve it, ....thanks!

Comment: ANY HAVE NOW I GOT IT  THANK U FOR UR COOPERATION

Answer (score 1):

If u want to change the layouts u must create new Activity classes in your source folder and in on create u set the content view to the layout u want.Also don't forget to add the activity in the Manifest file inside application, for example:
                                       
There are many ways to do this but I like to do it like this:

define a button :Button btnSignIn;
then in on Create set the layout and initialize the button:
                       btnSignIn =(Button)findViewByid(R.id.btnSingIn); 
                       btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);

u will get an error ,but put yout mouse pointer over the set onClick...and select let 'your main ActivityClass'impelment onClickListener.And then the same on the main class and select add unimplemented methods:This will ad a set onClick(View v)method,and here u can do something like this:

```
  switch(v.getID()){
```

case R.id.btnSingIn:
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignIn.class));
    break;
case R. ...//and u can continue.

However I don't know if u can change layouts without starting a new activity.If u find out 
reply pls:)).

Hope it helped!

}